# What is the reason for getting a pip error

Tags: python, pip

I want to make a discord bot and when I write ''pip install discord'', an error occurs.
This pops up:

```
The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I did try updating it but it didn't work

Comment: Did you try `pip3`?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install discord`

Comment: Can you run python with for instance `python3`? Then you may be able to do `python3 -m pip install discord`.

Comment: the python3 one seems to work, ill respond if my code works

Comment: ok it doesnt work. im basically using this tutorial to make the bot: https://youtu.be/fU-kWx-OYvE
i writed the entire code from 4:42 to 5:51 but it doesnt work

Comment: when installing python you probably didn't check the install pip option, you can install python again and mark the option to install pip or search online how to install it(its not hard)

Comment: alright, i added the pip thing to python. now the terminal is saying the requirement is already satisfied, which basically doesnt install the discord module thing since i tested the code